# List files in a homebrew package before installing it?

Tags: homebrew

As my title says, is there a way to see the list of files to be installed before installing the package?

Here is an actual scenario. I wanted the `mencoder` command. `brew search mencoder` doesn't show it. I google-searched for it and learned that `mencoder` usually comes  with `mplayer`.  But, I still didn't know whether the `mplayer` package of homebrew includes `mencode` or not. (In the end, I went ahead and installed the `mplayer` package and found the `mencoder` command in it.  After the installation, `brew ls mplayer` lists the files.)

I imagine that there is a website that shows a "directory" of all the packages . . .  (I visited https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ and searched for `mencoder` but failed. I looked at the `mplayer` package but didn't know how to look up its contents.)

**Edit:** `brew info mplayer` doesn't show files contained in the package, before or after its installation. `brew deps mplayer` only shows dependencies between packages.  It doesn't show the files contained in a single package.

Answer (score 0):

Does `brew info <formula>` work for you? (it would list all the dependencies)

```
brew info mplayer
mplayer: stable 1.5 (bottled), HEAD
UNIX movie player
...
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔, yasm ✘
Required: fontconfig ✔, freetype ✔, libcaca ✘
...
```

or `brew deps --graph mpplayer`, it would visualize the dependency tree.
[image]

update1: update to use `mplayer` instead of `node`

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, neither `info` or `deps` works. I've edited my question to include that point.

Comment: @Ryo, I updated the answer to use `mplayer` instead of `node`, let me know if that works.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I'm afraid I have to repeat that you are showing dependencies **between packages**.  What I'm after is a way to display the list of **files contained in a SINGLE package**.  Specifically, what files are contained in the package `mplayer`?  I already know the answer: a file named `mencoder` is contained in the package.  Your dependency output doesn't include `mencoder` in it, right?  This is because `mencoder` isn't the name of a package which `mplayer` depends on. Dependency lists only the names of the packages, not the individual files.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it is package list rather individual file list.

Comment: Do you know if any other package system support the individual file search feature? Could not that be done by a simple file search instead?

Comment: Yes. Before moving to macOS, I used Debian Linux. Its package system can show the files before installation of the package.  Also, there are websites hosting the packages, where you can search files.  So, I was wondering if there is such a web archive for homebrew.

Comment: Yeah, homebrew does not snapshot the files (internally we had similar questions and discussions). It also caused the checksum mismatch when upstream re-tag or re-release the artifacts.

Comment: I can feel you. Not sure if we already have something in the backlog for such feature (but also compared to debian, we are a bit small :) )

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  Just for your information, Debian's "apt-file" https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file seems to be a separate program from the main package manager.